# Calculating $\arctan(3)$ using Taylor series

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

I'm trying to get a Taylor series equivalent for $\arctan(3)$, but the standard definition for $\arctan(x)$ is restricted to $|x| \le 1$. How can I get a Taylor series for this expression?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would suggest using the fact that $\arctan(3)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan(1/3)$.